# Wrong columns while importing schema from Excell sheet in Azure Data flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

My input file is Excel which is on DatalakeGen2 blob.Am using Excel connector in Azure data flow and specified all the filename,path,cotainer .But its showing me the wrong Columns When i import schema ,But when I preview the data in Dataset level ,the columns are coming fine.

Below are the images which explain better.My original Excel file has some formatting done like shown below.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: try recreating dataset I also tried but getting column names as it is.

Comment: Tried .Same results. Does formatting cause any issue here because excel has formatted like there are changes in fonts,colors ,borders etc??

Comment: Did you try in Dataflow or in Dataset?At Dataset level,Schema is correctly im porting.But at dataflow ,in import projection,its giving me wrong Columns.

Comment: tried in data flow [image](https://i.imgur.com/3A9uukC.png)

Comment: even after editing getting same results.

Comment: Its alreadu formatted excel ,am loading that.I am just asking like all the formating things like Bold,underline,cell colrs has to be removed ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252412/discussion-between-pratik-lad-and-surya-teja532).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Resolved.I just removed all the formatting things in my file.Now its fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try checking the header checkbox while creating the dataset for this excel file. If already created, please check the header option in the dataset.

Comment: Tried. Bit thats not the reason. Its the formatting , i cleared all the formatting things and again projevted the file.Now it works fine. I think a formatted csv file camt be read correctly at dataflow level